# Как переустановить OS на макбуке?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, apple, ос

Имеется Macbook где-то 2009 года, на нем стоит только Windows. Нужно переустановить систему на более новый Windows или поставить MacOS. Создал образ Windows как для винды, но после выбора флешки как загрузочной он зависает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать загрузочную флешку для макбука?

Answer (score 0):

[Инструкция по созданию загрузочной флешки macOS](https://lifehacker.ru/kak-sdelat-zagruzochnuyu-fleshku-macos/)

Comment: Тут установка происходит пр помощи macOS, у меня ее нету

Answer (score 0):

Увы, для Вашего мака уже нет актуальной версии MacОС. Как устанавливать новый Windows - не знаю.

Две вещи, которые я вам порекомендовал бы, это установить Ubuntu или же купить более новый компьютер. Компьютер 10 летней давности уже с трудом может работать с современными программами.

Кстати, ниже требования для установки новой OS на Мак

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне не нужна последняя версия, а нужно лишь как создать образ для мака, через windows